# what is best way to show additional pages to users base on user Role in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

in fact, I want to show some extra pages to admin after login by User role like [admin or super user], and in my idea road map will provide by show additional link in the toolbar.
what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in your navigation bar or side bar where you have links like `Home, Dashboard, About, Logout` etc, we add extra links or navigation buttons which are hidden for other users and rendered only for specific users or user roles.

Or

You can have footer menu with `Admin Menu` and once we click we load `Admin Dashboard or Manage` page with all extra pages links. For non admin users you shouldn't load this page rather you should show pop up saying you are not admin.

Comment: for the first solution, we should design two different sidebar and root page? , that one is for the usual client and other one with an additional link for admin users?

Comment: No not all, you need conditionally render menus or links based on user role on side bar or root page. That's the ideal